# Fetching tables from my sql database

Tags: java, sql, jsp

I have a table in sql database which contain name,roll no,grade and i want to retreive that table from database and want to display that record on my jsp page in form of table....

```
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("select * from result where ROLLNO=?");  
stmt.setInt(1,roll);  

out.print("<table width=50% border=1>");  
out.print("<caption>Result:</caption>");  

  ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery();  

 /* Printing column names */  
  ResultSetMetaData rsmd=rs.getMetaData();  
  int total=rsmd.getColumnCount();  
     out.print("<tr>");  
   for(int i=1;i<=total;i++)  
  {  
   out.print("<th>"+rsmd.getColumnName(i)+"</th>");  
 }  

 out.print("</tr>");  

/* Printing result */  

 while(rs.next())  
  {  
 out.print("<tr><td>"+rs.getInt(1)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(2)+"</td>                <td>"+rs.getString(3)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(4)+"</td></tr>");
```

this code displays the result on separate html page

Comment: `want to display that record on my jsp page in form of table` so where is your `JSP` ?

Comment: what do you mean by separeate html page?

Comment: Are you using JSP or Servlets?